# Getting error when calling Power BI Embed Report Export To PDF API

Tags: powerbi-embedded

We are using Power BI c# SDK to export Power BI report in PDF.
We setup app registration in Azure Active Directory and assigned the required permissions. We Have power-bi-embedded A4 Plan
Some time pdf is generated and some time its not.
When its not generated, following error is thrown:
"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'".

Try to export pdf using Dot Net Power BI Sdk.
i am working with 4 reports deployed on power bi service & this functionality is working with other report, but same time failed in one report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3UTz.png)